# SCM with locks vs. concurrent merges and team size

Tags: version-control

What is the ideal number of programmers for lock based SCM not to become a severe issue in development?

**Edit:**

Fundamentally, I am not asking if there are merits to locking or merging (that is an unresolvable flame war). I am asking for the number of programmers where locking becomes a serious problem. I myself have found 4 to a good number, but this assumes the following

- most everybody works in the same office within yelling distance
- work is mostly disjoint (which makes locking not an issue except for common files {side note: my experiences is that merging is the best when there are little to no common files to accomplish tasks, which could be a series of questions on how does one organize code to such that common files are not needed by more than one person).
- the build can't be broken by premature lock release/commit.

Comment: why use locks at all? Merge is your friend!

Comment: @Mitch-Wheat, when peers refuse to run a webserver to develop code against, SVN commit local/update remote starts to be cumbersome to the process. Using locks let a single server be shared.

Comment: You are IMO trying to solve the **wrong problem** which is to not use one webserver per developer. Why do they refuse? Why do they feel this has more flaws than advantages? I don't get it.

Comment: It boils down the fact that they use windows (refuse to use linux) and we work with linux servers. our software does not behave well on Windows due to a few Windows/Apache2 bugs especially with Vista. I invented a special SCM called Gravity to provide a virtual HD to all clients that used locks. It worked well, but it required everyone in the office.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ideal number of programmers when using exclusive lock is **1**. Above, it's just painful, annoying, frustrating, etc. So, unless you're a team of BAs working on things that can't be merged (like word documents), don't do it, be real men/programmers and merge!

Answer (score 1):

Locks are an outdated concept. Even for a single developer - create a lock on your laptop, go attempt to work on another PC, and oops, you've got to manually intervene. With merge style SCM, you don't even have to think about it.